# Annotations needed to validate request data from set of values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8

Is there any annotation provided by spring to validate the input values from predefined set ?

**Requirement** validate roles assign to user, and Role value should be either `user`, `admin`, `moderator`.

Can I validate at the time when request comes in controller ?

Comment: You can try to create custom validator - like this https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Enum type to define the expected constants:

```
Role {
  USER,
  ADMIN, 
  MODERATOR
}
```

And then, your request would be:

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    @NotNull(message = "role cannot be null")
    private Role role;
}
```

Comment: But if we are just checking notNull it will accept other values than defined how can I validate that ?

Comment: Spring does the validation behind the scenes. Give it a try.